# Cmake doesn't recognize custom command as valid source

Tags: gcc, build, cmake

I have a problem modifying existing CMake based build-system. All I want to do is add different build rule for some of .c files. For the sake of this problem, I will focus on only one file.

The simplified directories tree looks like this

Project:

```
./src
 - file_of_interest.c
 - CmakeFiles.txt
other_files.c
CmakeFiles.txt
```

So in order to compile file_of_interest.c in a different way I do:

```
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file_of_interest.s
        COMMAND xt-xcc -S ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file_of_interest.c
        DEPENDS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/file.c
        COMMENT "Generating file_of_interest.s"
    )
add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file_of_interest.c.o
        COMMAND xt-xcc ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file_of_interest.s -o file_of_interest.c.o -c
        DEPENDS  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file_of_interest.s
        COMMENT "Generating file_of_interest.c.o"
    )

message(" ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} \n ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")

target_sources(target_name PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file_of_interest.c.o)
```

As you can see I used CMake's message() to print paths to be sure all is set up properly. It should work, but it doesn't! I expect CMake to register file_of_interest.c.o as source of target_name (and this is probably working), then "tie" it with my custom command which produces OUTPUT `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file_of_interest.c.o` and then to tie again `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file_of_interest.c.o` with OUTPUT `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/file_of_interest.s` and this certainly doesn't happen as CMake shows error message saying `CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:170 (add_executable): Cannot find source file: path/file_of_interest.c.o`

The path is OK. So the question is why does CMake cannot recognize recipes for that file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you create an executable (call `add_executable`) in the **top-level** `CMakeLists.txt`, but `add_custom_command` are called from the **subdirectory** (`src/CMakeLists.txt`).

This doesn't work: when CMake processes `add_executable` and searches for the commands generating its sources, it sees only `add_custom_commands` created in the **same** `CMakeLists.txt`.

From the `add_custom_command` [documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/add_custom_command.html):

> A **target** created in the **same directory** (`CMakeLists.txt` file) that specifies any output of the custom command as a source file is given a rule to generate the file using the command at build time.

It is unrelated that `target_sources` is called from the same directory as `add_custom_command`: the **target** is created by `add_executable` command, and `target_sources` just modifies its properties.

Comment: that is the case indeed. Btw, is there a way to ask cmake for intermediate step in build? For example I would like to go with explicit stages *.c -> *.s -> *.o -> binary

Comment: I don't know a way for adding an additional step in compile-link chain. But your way with `add_custom_command` generating an object file is actually a good approach. Just make sure that this `add_custom_command` is issued in the same `CMakeLists.txt` as `add_executable`.